# How to separate and create unique objects in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python and I have small racing console game project.
But I faced such problem:
When I want to create an object (e.g. tire type) I'm using Tire class for it, but when I edit "stock_tire" in one place, it is edited in all of them.
I don't want to create separate variable for each instance, is there any option to do that?

Here is my code:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, model, tire):
        self.model = model
        self.tire = tire
    def print_me(self):
        print(f"{self.model} with tires {self.tire.wear}")

class Tire:
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type
        self.wear = 100


stock_tire = Tire("stock")
celica = Car("Toyota Corolla", stock_tire)

civic = Car("Honda Civic", stock_tire)

celica.tire.wear -= 5
celica.print_me()
civic.print_me()
```

This code results in:

```
Toyota Corolla with tires 95
Honda Civic with tires 95
```

- looking how does the **new** works
- trying to use tires inheritance
- searching for "how to create unique object in python"

Comment: That output is correct, you are referencing exact same `object` namely `stock_tire`. To fix this you need to use `celica = Car("Toyota Corolla", Tire("stock")) civic = Car("Honda Civic", Tire("stock"))`. This creates new `Tire` object for both cars.

Comment: @patioFurnitureIsCool Thanks, so I have to create new object every time. Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you may find it informative to check out how to implement a `__str__` function in your Car class.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comment, you could make a new Tire object each time while initializing a Car object.

```
celica = Car("Toyota Corolla", Tire("stock"))
civic = Car("Honda Civic", Tire("stock"))
```

Another way is to make [copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html?highlight=copy#module-copy) of the tire object while initializing Car:

```
import copy
class Car:
    def __init__(self, model, tire):
        self.model = model
        self.tire = copy.deepcopy(tire)
    def print_me(self):
        print(f"{self.model} with tires {self.tire.wear}")
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to create a new object every time if you use inheritance. So for example, the `Car` class could inherit from the `Tyre` class.

Also, as a side note, you can replace the `print_me()` with the builtin `__repr__()` which helps with the print statements.

It would work like this:

```py
class Tire:
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type
        self.wear = 100

class Car(Tire):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super().__init__(type)
        self.model = model

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.model} with tires {self.wear}"


stock_tire = Tire("stock")
celica = Car("Toyota Corolla")
civic = Car("Honda Civic")

celica.wear -= 5
print(celica)
print(civic)
```

This would return:

```
Toyota Corolla with tires 95
Honda Civic with tires 100
```

Comment: This doesn't scale well. For example, if a car should have 4 tires, you would get into trouble.

Comment: Also, what's `type` in `Car.__init__`?

Comment: @mkrieger1,  i suppose that the OP will need to think about the datastructure (and the physics and mechanics) of the problem to hand. If you have a more scaleable solution, it would be helpful to propose such...

Comment: It's already shown in codeforester's answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you inherit both the classes you don't need to create separate objects then. You just called out the parent class object and it will worked.Hope that helps you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).